# Require a JSON file and cast to interface to validate all fields are present

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to read in a json file with `require()`, and I want to cast it to a type and have the cast fail if the file I'm reading does not have all the fields required by the interface.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
export interface Config {
    userAgent: string
    refreshToken: string
    clientId: string
}

export class ConfigLoader {
    config: Config

    constructor() {
        try {
            this.config = require('../config.json') as Config
        } catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

My thought was that if the config.json file doesn't have all three of the keys specified in the interface, the cast to Config would fail and I could catch it and use a default or something. But the require works fine and I just end up with a config object that's missing keys.

How can I validate that my `config.json` is a valid instance of `Config`?

Comment: typescript types don't exist in runtime, you need to do that check explicitly or using libraries. Check the following article: https://lorefnon.tech/2018/03/25/typescript-and-validations-at-runtime-boundaries/

Answer (score 1):

If your configuration is not dynamic at runtime. You can use `import` instead of require to load JSON with the right types and then validate that against an interface:

```
import * as rawConfig from './config.json'

export interface Config {
  userAgent: string
  refreshToken: string
  clientId: string
}

export const config: Config = rawConfig
```

One thing to keep in mind is that since TypeScript is structurally typed it will not detect if the config.json has more fields than the ones specified in the interface.

Comment: How is it different to what OP already has? Wouldn't it still happily accept any rubbish you pass to it?

Comment: @zerkms JSON files are typed since 2.9 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule

So if inside the file field types won't match or there will be missing fields it will be a compile time error.

Comment: Oh, that's what I totally did not know yet, thanks, and my apologies.